# Is base class loaded content duplicated in the derived class?

Tags: c#, loading, monogame, derived-class, base-class

**Is base class loaded content duplicated in the derived class?**

I have a base class 'GameScreen' and numerous derived classes ('TitleScreen', 'PlayerSetupScreen', 'GameplayScreen', etc.). If I load graphics content (which is common to all screens) in the base class 'GameScreen', will that content be duplicated in RAM for each derived screen, or is it loaded the one time and simply referenced? I'm assuming the latter, but I just need to be certain, as I intend to load a lot more content this way. Any help would be appreciated.

I am coding in C# Monogame, using Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually, this question is too ambiguous. Yet I feel you're wrong both ways. classes will not share data unless its static. if you load data in one class, the other will not see it in any normal sense, and unless you made them all reference the same data

Comment: This really is OOP basics, and too broad for here.

Comment: A base class just defines a *type* from which subclasses derive their definitions. It has nothing to do with the *instances* of those classes sharing data or anything like that.

Comment: @seesharper Sure it does. `public class A { protected object a; } public class B : A {}`. The field `a` is shared.

Comment: @CodingYoshi If I have an `Animal` class and a `Giraffe` class derived from `Animal`, and `Animal` has some field X (reference type but doesn't matter), then sure, `Giraffe`s will have a field X. But instances of `Giraffe`s don't share *data* with instances of `Animal`s - obviously! - except insofar as a `Giraffe` 'shares' data with itself as an instance of `Animal`.

Comment: @seesharper Hmm.. this seems to be a divided issue. Any definitive solutions to avoid content duplication would be most grateful.

Comment: @Drekinn there is no chance of content duplication in C# with something like graphics content unless you go out of your way to copy it. It will always be assigned by reference. What is unclear is how your different class instances (like TitleScreen) will share the graphics content loaded into GameScreen in practice. The data would need to be `static` for this to occur automatically.

Comment: If the derived classes use the properties/fields or wherever you have the graphics in from the base class, and it's the **same instance** your assumption is correct: It will be one time.

Comment: @seesharper Yes, I've designated the GameScreen Texture2D graphics variables as `static`, and all seems to be working well. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I have never used monogame... But with other game engines like unity certain assets will be "shared" when used many times... the way this is achieved is through having just a reference to the asset.  Seems like some of the opinions here are about C#... But C# not always works the same depending on the game engine.. For example in Unity C# is just a "scripting" language and will be ultimately "translated" to C++.  So for this reason the "well known facts" about C# do not always apply in game engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would be much clearer if you posted some code showing what you've done but I think I understand so I'll do it for you. I'm assuming you have something like this:

```cs
public abstract class GameScreen
{
    protected Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
}

public class TitleScreen : GameScreen
{
}

public class GameplayScreen : GameScreen
{
}
```

And somewhere else in your code you're doing something like this:

```
var titleScreen = new TitleScreen { Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("something") };
var gameplayScreen = new GameplayScreen { Texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("something") };
```

Put simply, in this code MonoGame will only load the "something" texture once and cache it inside the `ContentManager`. When the same content is loaded the second time the `ContentManager` will return a reference to the same instance of the content.

What this effectively means is that each "screen" will only carry around a reference pointer to the content it cares about. This won't take up much RAM so don't worry about it.

What could take up a lot of RAM is calling `Content.Load` many times to load *different* content. The `ContentManager` won't unload this content until it is disposed or unloaded explicitly even if nothing is holding a reference to it.

That said, it's highly unlikely you'll need to worry about any of this stuff until your game becomes much larger. Don't over complicate things until they become a real problem. You can always refactor your code later if you start to notice issues.

Comment: Thanks for the informative feedback. It's reassuring to know duplicate content is via reference only. I decided to load the common content in the main Game class so that it's always ready.